# What is this line in code actually saying?

Tags: python, function

I have been running though a lot of examples in python and got to this function code.  I can not seem to understand this code, specifically what line 6 is saying (starts with row = )

```
def pascal(n):
    row = [1]
    y = [0]
    for x in range(n):
        print(row)
        row = [l+r for l, r in zip(row+y, y+row)]
    return n
pascal(4)
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: That's a list comprehension. Basically works the same as the `map` function, but also allows for filtering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it is probably a better link, actually.